# How to separate unnormalized table into groups where ID 0 then all rows below until ID 0 is reached again?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an access database and I imported the data into SQL, that went fine. Now that I am looking over the data, it looks very odd. There's no normalization anywhere. I did not design this database.

I'm going to try and explain as best as I can
Group_Name that has an Option_ID of 0 will be a header, then every Group_Name after the Option_ID of 0 is part of the Group_Name that has an Option_ID of 0 until it reaches the next Option_ID of 0 then repeats itself again.

I know that I should have provided some statements, but I have no idea where to begin.

Pic 1 is how it looks, pic 2 how its separated, pic 3 is the next group and its options, this table goes on and on for about 140 rows

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: How the data looks]
[image: How it needs to be separated]
[image: Second separation etc..]

Comment: Can you possibly add an incremental id column (e.g, 1,2,3,4...) when you import these rows? That would give them an order and enable writing your query.

Comment: I could but all group_names and its option_name vary, one group_name could have 3 options, then another group_name might have 10 option_names. So the only way to keep track of things is by the zero in the Option_ID column, because I still need to work with the existing access database that they are using

Comment: I would suggest that you dump the data in Excel, fix it there, and then re-import it into a database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that is one way to go, but that raises an issue if the existing access database gets updated, then I will have to continuously do that. The sql database still needs to work with the existing access database. I am thinking that a loop is needed, and its been a very long while since I have done a loop in SQL.

Comment: @Chris . . . I would suggest fixing the data structure to be what you need and then implementing views in Access so existing applications can use it.  I realize that may not be feasible.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I am starting to think that my only option is fix the structure, and hope that the existing access database doesn't get updated and if it does then just suck it up and manually make the addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group the rows in a single `SELECT` statement, you need to be able to preserve the source table row sequence, otherwise we don't know which row belongs to which group.

Here is a generalized solution. The only assumption I made is that you were able to add a column (`C0`) at the time of import. This helps to preserve the source table row sequence. `C1` corresponds to your `Group_Name` or `Order_Name` columns, `C2` is the `Option_ID` column.

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    (C0 int, C1 varchar(2), C2 int)
;  
INSERT INTO T1
    (C0, C1, C2)
VALUES
    (0, 'A1', 0),
    (1, 'A2', 1),
    (2, 'A3', 2),
    (3, 'B1', 0),
    (4, 'B3', 3),
    (5, 'B4', 4),
    (6, 'C1', 0)
;
select T2.C1 as GR, T1.*
  from T1
  join (select C0, C1
          from T1 
         where C2 = 0) as T2
    on T1.C0 >= (select C0 
                   from T1 
                  where C1 = T2.C1) 
   and T1.C0 <  (select min(C0)
                   from T1
                  where C2 = 0
                    and C0 > (select C0 
                                from T1 
                               where C1 = T2.C1))
;
```

Result:

```
GR  C0  C1  C2
A1  0   A1  0
A1  1   A2  1
A1  2   A3  2
B1  3   B1  0
B1  4   B3  3
B1  5   B4  4
```

Comment: Thanks, I think think I can work with that, thanks for taking the time to figure it out. Its much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's only 140 rows, I'd bite the bullet and create two tables now - one for the group names and one for the group options, the latter with a foreign key relationship to the former.

Comment: I would, but those ID's that are under the Option_ID's are foreign keyed to somewhere else, and if the existing access database has updates to it then there will be a conflict between the SQL and Access Database. I am only keeping the database as is because it has to work with the existing access database.